# Salt-stack error with state git.config

Tags: git, salt-stack

I've run into this error while trying to use the git.config state with saltstack version 2014.7.2 (Helium). I'm also using a masterless setup.

```
----------
    State: - git
    Name:      user.email
    Function:  config
        Result:    False
        Comment:   State git.config found in sls git is unavailable

        Changes:
```

The state generating this error is here:

```
git:
  pkg.installed

gitConfigEmail:
  git.config:
    - name: user.email
    - value: {{pillar['user']['email']}}
    - is_global: True
    - require:
      - pkg: git
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try refreshing your states and modules to the minions http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/#modules-are-easy-to-write

Comment: I cut and pasted the state as presented (with a hardcoded pillar value) and it works for me.  Try isolating just those two state definitions and running it on your end.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `git.config_set` state, not the git.config module.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.git.html#salt.states.git.config_set